# setting up useraccounts:bootstrap in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I setup useraccounts:bootstrap with blaze, installed user accounts password and useraccounts:flow-routing

on the server I have this code so far:

```
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import { BlazeLayout } from 'meteor/kadira:blaze-layout';
import { AccountsTemplates} from 'meteor/useraccounts:bootstrap';

// Import needed templates
import '../../ui/layouts/body/body.js';
import '../../ui/pages/home/home.js';
import '../../ui/pages/not-found/not-found.js';



AccountsTemplates.configure({
  defaultLayout: 'App_body',
  defaultContentRegion: 'main',
  defaultLayoutRegions: {}
});

// Define these routes in a file loaded on both client and server
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {
  name: 'signin',
  path: '/signin'
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signUp', {
  name: 'join',
  path: '/join'
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('forgotPwd');

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('resetPwd', {
  name: 'resetPwd',
  path: '/reset-password'
});
```

App_body and main are set up correctly because my other routes work with the header and nav bar of the site, but when I go to /signin it returns a 404 , I can't find how to enter the useraccounts:bootstrap routes, any help?

thanks

Comment: "// Define these routes in a file loaded on both client and server"

Comment: I did and still won't work... my Auth_page template look like this  <template name="Auth_page">
 <div class"container">
  {{> atForm}}
</div>


</template>